VBA object variable not being recognized
Table k is a keywords table with 2 records in field "Key":  Lost and Slow (see image).  A second table Comments has 4 comments in it containing Lost or Slow (see image).  I am looping through the keywords then searching for Lost and Slow in Comments table, then I am storing the Refnum (foreign key) and the keyword in the third table Mariners for future reference/joining.  The SQL SET event stores the value of kk in Mariners.KW field. Here is code and images.
Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim k As DAO.Recordset
Dim kk As Field, key
Set k = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("keywords")
    For Each kk In k.Fields
            Dim sql As String
                sql = "UPDATE Comments LEFT JOIN Mariners ON Comments.RefNum = Mariners.Refnum " & _
                " SET Mariners.KW = '" & kk & "'"
            DoCmd.RunSQL sql
    Next
End Sub   

Keywords table

Comments table

Mariner table


Have you tried removing this line? Set kk = Keywords.Fields(key) - It looks like it has no purpose anyway.

I'm not good at this yet, but I thought I had to specify (set) the field name before I loop through it

The For Each loop assigns to kk. Btw " SET Mariners.KW Like '* kk *'" looks suspect.

'* kk *' is the keyword (from field "key") in each loop that gets stored in the mariners.kw field during the update event.   I did remove the SET statement, and it now returns a SQL error.   Let me change the Like to =.   The Like should have been in the WHERE clause (that I disabled for this)

Your SET clause makes no sense. Can't SET to a wildcarded value. Why do you even JOIN these tables for an UPDATE action? Your code will UPDATE every record in each loop iteration because there is no WHERE clause. Edit question to show sample data and desired result as formatted text tables.

Sorry @June7, I agree.   Let me re-frame it in the Question.

Let me delete this question and restate it clean.   Sorry

Third time's a charm? Why not just edit this question?

I just learned I can't post for 90 minutes.   I'll edit, sorry, getting the hang of things.

Data should be posted as formatted text, not images https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support. Not seeing Mariners table nor desired result. Your code will still UPDATE every record in each loop iteration.

Added Mariner table.    I agree each record will update in Mariner table for the keyword it's comparing against, but for the "next" keyword, I don't see how the SQL event will otherwise know to evaluate the 2nd keyword without the For/Next.  Appreciate your patience as I improve.   (last image not formatted text, my fault)

None of your data is posted as formatted text. Did you review the link? Why no RefNum data in Mariners table? Open the edit history and review the edits I did to your question.

What 'future joining' do you have in mind? Most likely there are ways to accomplish whatever you want without having to periodically run this UPDATE action.

As we collect monthly feedback from the customer the table Mariner will grow as the table holding the keyword and Refnum.    When the staff wants to evaluate all the "Lost" they would join the Mariner table to the comment table, filtered by lost and see the actual/entire comment.   My job is to do the keyword search in Comments, then store the customer number (REfnum) along with the keyword so the staff can go back later and look at the longer comment.   (I'm using a Test table here, but actual comments can be longer than 256K in one instance).

I think the code edits below are perfect!  Let me try them.  I have not used db.execute sql before so I appreciate that.

@June7, the code works perfectly, and the Mariner table updates for Lost and for Slow.  I see where I went wrong.  You refer to the field as k!key and I was thinking of kk as a variable of Key (cause I'm still learning).   By changing to table/field, that's exactly what was needed.   Again, I appreciate your patience and I'll be more attentive to this site as I go along.   A big Thank YOu!

Could have used a variable for the field value (kk = k!key), I just didn't think it was necessary. The sql variable isn't really needed either, could db.Execute "UPDATE ....

So what should happen if a Cmt contained more than one keyword? Is this a possibility? Are there more keywords than the two in example?

Quite possible, and if 2 keywords per cmt, then there would be two rows for the same refnum (survey monkey serial #).  But, because they are 2 separate keywords, I'll capture the update just fine in the Mariner table.  So, first goal is to capture each row where there is a keyword of "x" irrespective of single/multiple instance in 1 comment.     Then, doing an inner join of Refnum on Mariners table, and Group By, we can trim it to one survey comment and another inner join on the comments table will join the keywords with the actual comment itself.   Your solution is perfect! and tested fine.

Sorry, yes more than 2 keywords, but not excessive - just enough for quality staff to analyze.   So, slow, lost, poor service, unresponsive, never received, damaged, etc.    And, a separate table for "positive" keywords.  (don't want to ignore positive even when we all attempt to improve the negative).    Thanks for asking, and for your explanations.   I learned ALOT during this exchange;  hope to engage down the road.

I have never seen For Each to loop recordset and reference recordset field. If you want to avoid popup warnings for action SQL, either use SetWarnings [True/False] or Execute. Without WHERE clause, EVERY record in table will UPDATE, not just the ones relevant to keyword.
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim k As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim sql As String
Set db = CurrentDb
Set k = db.OpenRecordset("keywords")
    Do While Not k.EOF            
        sql = "UPDATE Comments LEFT JOIN Mariners ON Comments.RefNum = Mariners.Refnum " & _
              " SET Mariners.KW = '" & k!key & "'"
              " WHERE Comments.Cmt LIKE '*" & k!key & "*'"
        db.Execute sql
        k.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub

